# Best practices for AngularJS CRUDS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figger out the best way to create CRUDS (Create/Read/Update/Delete) in AngularJS by calling API requests back and forth.

I've read some articles about code structure but still I'm not sure how to maintain a clean structure by creating those CRUDS.

In this project I'm using `ui-router` for state management.

```
.state('user', {
   url: "/user",
   templateUrl: "app/views/user/index.html",
   controller: "UserController as user",
   resolve: {
     data: ['UserService', function (UserService) {
       return UserService.all();
     }]
   }
})

.state('createUser', {
   url: "/user/create",
   templateUrl: "app/views/user/create.html",
   controller: "UserController as user"
})
```

What is the best way to make this work? Because I'm using the `data` variable, which is being resolved in my `user` state in the `UserController`, I'm not able to use the same `UserController` for my `createUser` state, because the injected variable cant be resolved.

Is there maybe any way I can check on this so I can just use the `UserController` for all my user-specific actions?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use the same controller if you want, eventhough it is usually a better to have a new controller for create action. Usually people either write a special controller for each CRUD action or sometimes they use the same controller for Create and Update.

In your specific case, if you want to use the same controller, just return an empty array of users as the data variable. Like this:

```
.state('user', {
   url: "/user",
   templateUrl: "app/views/user/index.html",
   controller: "UserController as user",
   resolve: {
       data: ['UserService', function (UserService) {
           return UserService.all();
       }]
   }
})

.state('createUser', {
   url: "/user/create",
   templateUrl: "app/views/user/create.html",
   controller: "UserController as user",
   resolve: {
     data: [function () {
       return [];
     }]
   }
})
```

Comment: How would it look like to have different controller for each CRUD action? What would be a good naming convention as well?

Comment: Well usually you create one view for listing all of the entities (ex: users.html or userList.html) and a controller for that view (usersCtrl.js). This view+controller usually only lists all the data and has links for adding a new entity, editing an entity or deleting an entity (delete is usually handled by the list controller as well because its very simple and no view is needed). Then you have a view+controller for adding a new entity (addUser.html and addUserCtrl.js) and a view/controller for editing. Adding user needs no data, editing needs the 1 entity. Sometimes these 2 are in one.